# How to ignore characters in InputStream?

Tags: java, inputstream

I want to have an `InputStream` which will ignore certain characters. For example, for given String:

> ch$ron$osy$nclast$ic_in$fundibu$lum

I want my `InputStream` to ignore all `$` characters, so it will be read as:

> chronosynclastic_infundibulum

The only option I've found so far is this implementation of [`ReplaceInputStream`](http://jscience.org/experimental/javadoc/org/jscience/io/ReplaceInputStream.html) in JScience library.

Are there any other (faster/more common) options to do this?

Comment: You can do it after you read the input by manipulating the string. Use public String method replaceAll(String regex, String replacement) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29  as for performance, I am not sure which would be faster

Comment: @Multithreader This certainly wouldn't be efficent.

Comment: it is not easy to tell how efficient is that. Or how efficient is the JScience library. They could be using replaceAll for their implementation...who knows? you would need to do performance measurements in order to give a conclusion...

Comment: What Multithreader said. I remember reading about performance hits with successive iterations of replace(regex), but it's hard to say "this approach is better" when it comes to various forms of string replacement.

Comment: @Multithreader No, they're doing this in more sophisticated way. [See source code](https://java.net/nonav/projects/jade/sources/svn/content/trunk/v1/src/org/jscience/io/ReplaceInputStream.java?rev=371).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer the old way :

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
    int i;
    while ((i = is.read()) != -1) {
        char c = (char) i;
        if (c != '$')
            sb.append(c);
    }

    InputStream nis =  new ByteArrayInputStream(sb.toString().getBytes());
```

Comment: As I mentioned, I want to have an **InputStream**, not just write this in console.

Comment: If u can skip `$`, rest is nothing but convert back to inputStream. For you convenience I've added the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it after you read the input by manipulating the string. Use [`public String method replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). As for performance, I am not sure which would be faster

A sample use:

```
String a = "ch$ron$osy$nclast$ic_in$fundibu$lum";
String b = a.replaceAll("[$]", "");
//b = "chronosynclastic_infundibulum"
```

You can implement your own `InputStream` that removes such characters so you will not deal with this on the application level.